# datepicker and timepicker modal dialog not showing set and cancel buttons

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

datepicker and timepicker modal dialog not showing set and cancel buttons 
in android Titanium Appcelerator!

```
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({

   type: Titanium.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
   value: new Date(),
   top:200

});
```

datepicker displaying without set and cancel buttons.
I can't find solution!

Comment: What type of set button you are referring to? like toolbar buttons?

Comment: " ok " and " cancel " buttons don't display only Day, Month and Year shows without any button in this modal dialog.

Comment: The picker modal does not work like the alert dialog box, so you need to create your own custom buttons.

Comment: if you have android phone, can u look at system settings -> Date and time -> Set date / Set time.

Comment: I want to do like this modal dialog

Comment: You have to do a trick to achieve this. Create a view, add the picker in the view, add your custom OK, Cancel buttons in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker();
                picker.showDatePickerDialog({
                    callback: function(e) {
                        if (e.cancel) {
                            Ti.API.info('user canceled dialog');
                        } else {
                            Ti.API.info('user selected date: ' + e.value);
                        }
                    }
                });
```